# How to switch between 2 colors in Java Jbuttons after every click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, tic-tac-toe

I have been making a color-based Tic Tac Toe game using Java Swing and Java AWT and have more or less finished the project, however there is still one problem that needs to be fixed in order to be a proper Tic Tac Toe game. The colors that are supposed to be used is Orange (X) and blue (O), however for some reason even when checking each turn iteration it refuses to switch colors after every click and at this point I am lost. Any help is appreciated

Board.java:

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

  boolean gameRunning = true;

  private final JButton[][] grid = new JButton[3][3];

  JFrame board;

  JPanel panel;

public Board() {
    initBoard();
}

private void makePanel() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    setBoard();
    board.add(panel);
}

private void initBoard() {

    int BOARD_WIDTH = 800;
    int BOARD_HEIGHT = 600;

    board = new JFrame();

    board.setTitle("JTicTacToe");

    board.setSize(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
    board.setResizable(false);
    board.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    board.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    makePanel();

    board.setVisible(true);

}

private void setBoard() {

    //Loop through 2D array
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            grid[row][col] = new JButton();
            grid[row][col].setOpaque(true);
            grid[row][col].setBorderPainted(false);
            grid[row][col].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
            panel.add(grid[row][col]);
        }
    }
    validate();
}


protected class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    Color defaultColor = new Color(238,238,238);


    protected void check(int moves) {
        //Rows
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
             if (!defaultColor.equals(grid[c][0].getBackground()) && grid[c][0].getBackground() == grid[c][1].getBackground() && grid[c][0].getBackground() == grid[c][2].getBackground()) {
                gameRunning = false;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over!");
            }
        }
        //Verticals
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            if (!defaultColor.equals(grid[0][c].getBackground()) && grid[0][c].getBackground() == grid[1][c].getBackground() && grid[0][c].getBackground() == grid[2][c].getBackground()) {
                    gameRunning = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over!");
            }
        }

        //Check diagonals
        if (!defaultColor.equals(grid[0][0].getBackground()) && grid[0][0].getBackground() == grid[1][1].getBackground() && grid[0][0].getBackground() == grid[2][2].getBackground()) {
            gameRunning = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over!");}

         if (!defaultColor.equals(grid[0][2].getBackground()) && grid[0][2].getBackground() == grid[1][1].getBackground() && grid[0][2].getBackground() == grid[2][0].getBackground()) {
            gameRunning = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over!");
        }

       //Check draw if game goes to 9 moves
        if(moves == 9) {
            gameRunning = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Draw!");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         int turns = 0;
                if (e.getSource() == grid[0][0]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[0][0].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[0][0].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == grid[0][1]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[0][1].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[0][1].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == grid[0][2]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[0][2].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[0][2].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == grid[1][0]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[1][0].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[1][0].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == grid[1][1]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[1][1].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[1][1].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == grid[1][2]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[1][2].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[1][2].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == grid[2][0]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[2][0].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[2][0].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == grid[2][1]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[2][1].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[2][1].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == grid[2][2]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[2][2].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[2][2].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid");
            }
                System.out.println(turns);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the code prettier:

- The variable `gameRunning` is set but it is never used. You can remove it and the program will still behave the same. Or you can start using it. But just giving it values without using those values is unnecessary work.
- The variables at the top should be `private` (`grid` is `private`, but eg `board` is not)
- You can use a loop to shorten the `actionPerformed` method (note that I added a `return;`):

  ```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                if (e.getSource() == grid[col][row]) {
                    turns++;
                    if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                        grid[col][row].setBackground(Color.orange);
                        check(turns);
                    } else {
                        grid[col][row].setBackground(Color.blue);
                        check(turns);
                    }
                    System.out.println(turns);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid");
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You set the variable `turns` to `0` every time a button is clicked (ie every time `actionPerformed` is called). You need to make `turns` global (same as eg `grid`).